# Javascript deserialize array

Tags: javascript, json, arrays

I have an array from JSON like this

```
"---\n- table\n- kevin\n- table\n- kevin\n"
```

How do i deserialize this array to something that is useful in javascript

Comment: That doesn't look like valid JSON

Comment: If you want to split a string, use the .split method of the string object. To split on newlines, var parts = yourString.split("\n");

Comment: That doesn't look like JSON to me.  If it was a JSON array it would look more like `["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]`.  See: http://www.json.org/fatfree.html

Comment: That doesn't look like an array either...

Comment: He probably means this particular attribute of the JSON array is an array, not that this is the entire JSON array

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Todd sayd the string is not a valid json object however you can still split it into an array like so :

```
var s = "---\n- table\n- kevin\n- table\n- kevin\n";
var arr = s.split('\n-'); // arr should now contain ["---", " table", " kevin", " table", "kevin"]
console.log(arr);
```

p.s. instead of '\n-' you can use any separator you whant to split a string into an array ( more info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) )

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want this:

```
var re = /\-\s(\w+)/g,
    arr = [],
    match;

while ( match = re.exec( str ) ) {
    arr.push( match[1] );
}
```

where `str` is your string.

As a result `arr` will be `[ 'table', 'kevin', 'table', 'kevin' ]`.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/DdTqC/2/